# Showing Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measurable space and $f$ be a real valued integrable function on $X$. Let  $E_n=\{x\in X: f(x)\geq nq\}$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and fixed $q>0$ . Show that
>
> - $\lim_{n \to \infty} \begin{equation*}
>   \int_{E_n} f d\mu
>   \end{equation*}=0$
> - $f\chi_{E_n}\to 0$ in measure $\mu$
> - $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu^*(E_n)=0$  ($\mu^*$ is outer measure corresponding $\mu$)

My attempt:

if $f\geq0$ then $\begin{equation*}
\int_{E_n} f d\mu
\end{equation*}=
\int_{X} f d\mu-\int_{X} f\chi_{E_n} d\mu
$
now because $f\chi_{E_n}$ is accending sequence of integrable functions that coverge to f almost every where by monotonic covergence theorem we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \begin{equation*}
\int_{E_n} f d\mu
\end{equation*}=0$$
so $f\chi_{E_n}\to 0$ in $L^1$ and hence $f\chi_{E_n}\to0$ in measure $\mu$

$E_n=f^{-1}([nq,\infty))$ and f is measurable so $E_n$ is measurable and hence  $$\mu^*(E_n)=\mu(E_n)$$

Comment: i added my attempt

Comment: +1 (I didn't downvote, but thanks for putting in your work...much appreciated)

Comment: So what's actually your question?

Comment: I was looking for tips or acknowledgment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt for the first question is good, or more directly, since $|f\chi_{E_n}| \leq |f|$ and $\int_X |f|d\mu < +\infty$, we can apply dominated convergence to say

$$\lim \int_{E_n}fd\mu = \lim \int_X f\chi_{E_n}d\mu = \int_X \lim f\chi_{E_n}d\mu = \int_X 0d\mu = 0$$

For the second one, you didn't prove it. You need to show for any $\epsilon >0$, we have

$$\mu\{x\in X : |f\chi_{E_n}|\geq \epsilon\} \to 0$$

Remark that $$\{x\in X : |f\chi_{E_n}|\geq \epsilon\} \subset E_n$$ so if we have $\mu(E_n) \to 0$, the second conclusion is proved.

Now we will prove the third one, then the third one implies the second one.

Since $E_n$ is measurable, replace the outer measure by measure to simplify, then remark that:

$$\mu(E_n)nq \leq \int_{E_n}fd\mu \leq \int_X |f|d\mu$$

Then it's easy to conclude